# The context cannot be used while the model is being created

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, entity, dbcontext

I'm getting a problem with my entity framework usage and think it could be because I'm using my DB context incorrectly.

Every now and then I'm seeing error messages in my log stating: "The context cannot be used while the model is being created."

The error doesn't always occur and seems to be on a fresh application load or if I compile my project and refresh a browser tab whilst it's compiling.

The function below is the one that is error'ing and is called from my master page.

```
public static class UserFunctions
{
    private static peopleSwimmingContext _db = new peopleSwimming.Models.peopleSwimmingContext();

    public static String GetUserRole(Int32 UserID) {

        String returnedRole = String.Empty;

        var foundUser = _db.Users.Where(w => w.UserId == UserID).FirstOrDefault();
        if (foundUser != null)
        {
            returnedRole = foundUser.Role.Name;
        }
        return returnedRole;
    }
}
```

Any tips would be massively appreciated!

Oh and here is my innerstack trace:

Inner Stack Trace:

at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) at peopleSwimming.Logic.UserFunctions.GetUserRole(Int32 UserID) in c:\svn\peopleSwim\peopleSwimming\Logic\UserFunctions.cs:line 18 at peopleSwimming._Home.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\svn\peopleSwim\peopleSwimming\Home.aspx.cs:line 25 at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your code in a `using` statement that initializes and disposes of the data context so it's only available from right before you need it to just afterwards. This will also ensure it's disposed of.

Also, you don't need the `Where` method, you can just use `FirstOrDefault`.

```
public static class UserFunctions
{
    public static String GetUserRole(Int32 UserID) 
    {
        using (peopleSwimmingContext _db = new peopleSwimming.Models.peopleSwimmingContext())
        {
            String returnedRole = String.Empty;

            var foundUser = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(w => w.UserId == UserID);

            if (foundUser != null)
            {
                returnedRole = foundUser.Role.Name;
            }

            return returnedRole;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on the where statements in first or default and the using blocks. I've changed this function to use the using block so hopefully I will see the error less frequently!

Comment: Did you see it less frequently?